# How to deactivate IR-Lights

Tags: hardware, flashlight

My IR-Flashlights are not turning off anymore.

Turning the IR-Cam on/off, rebooting the phone, turning off the phone, factory-reset etc. didn't work. It stays on all the time, even when the phone powers itself off due to low battery.

I now rooted my phone and hoped that I may be able to manually deactivate it via /sys/class/ but could not find the directory associated with the IR-hardware.

Any suggestions how I could find the correct directory?
Or any other suggestion how I could turn off the lights?

I have an Ulefone Armor 11 5G.